# How to use multiple sorting in yii1 search function?

Tags: php, yii

Here is my Code ...

```
'sort'=>array(
  'defaultOrder'=>'is_current DESC'
        )
```

I want to use multiple sort with is_current.

Comment: Could you provide more details?

Comment: what do you mean by "multiple sort"? Is it a plugin, an extension; OR do you want to sort using multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `CSort::attribtes` property:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort/#attributes-detail

You can describe all possible combinations of sorting there.
For example:

```
'sort'=>array(
  'defaultOrder'=>'is_current DESC',
  'attributes' => array(
    'field_1'=>array(
      'asc'=>'is_current, field_1',
      'desc'=>'is_current DESC, field_1 DESC',
      'label'=>'Field 1'
    ),
    'field_2'=>array(
      'asc'=>'is_current, field_2',
      'desc'=>'is_current DESC, field_2 DESC',
      'label'=>'Field 2'
    ),
    ...
  ) 
)
```